# Change audio/source tag download name

Tags: javascript, html, audio, download

I was wondering if like on the  tag there is also a download attribute for the audio/source tag to change the filename for the download

or doing it with some javascript stuff

right now the name is just some random string since the audio is created from a Blob

Comment: Can you show your HTML thus far?  Are you referring to the download button some browsers put on the default audio player?

Comment: @Brad ``` <audio controls> <source :src=clip.src type="audio/ogg"> </audio>``` when you right click a audio or source tag and you click "Save audio as" and then the filename that comes into the save file dialog. i want to change that to something else than the random string from the blob

Comment: Give us the code

Comment: this.media_recorder.onstop = e => {
       let clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip');

       // Get sound blob from media recorder chunk data
       let blob = new Blob(this.chunks, {
        'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'
       });

       // Create clip object
       let clip = {
        local_id: this.clips.length,
        name: clipName,
        blob: blob,
        src: window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
       };

Comment: I don't see how the code should change anything on the question. There is no documented `name` attribute on the HTML Audio element to define a name when users download the file, such as the `download` attribute of `a` elements defines. When the server serves a file with hashed name (where the title of the file is resolved somewhere else) then users download a file with a weird hash name, causing lots of confusion for some of them.